# getenv() doesn't show all variables, even if they are set

Tags: php, apache

I'm testing setting environment variables in .htaccess for my php code to use, and facing strange behaviour from the `getenv()` function.

---

In my .htaccess, I set

```
SetEnv BOP 23
```

And in my php, I successfully get

```
$res = getenv("BOP");
echo($res);
>>>>  23
```

But when I try to `var_dump(getenv());` or use debugger to see what is in the array returned by `getenv()`, I get an array of length 23 BUT my "BOP" variable is missing.

---

For example, if I try to dump `getenv()` into an array and make a lookup:

```
$array = getenv();

echo($array["BOP"])
```

I get an exception:

```
Exception has occurred.
Notice: Undefined index: BOP
```

---

From what I read here about `getenv()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

> ... If `varname` is omitted, **all** environment variables are returned as associative array.

So what am I missing? Why can I access my variable but isn't it in `getenv()`?

Comment: how are you running the script? is it via a browser or via CLI? Also if via browser, check your AllowOverride directive to check the permitted types allowed for .htaccess

Comment: via browser. and AllowOverride is set to All for the directory that holds this .htaccess and the rest of the code. But how would `getenv("BOP")` return anything at all if it wasn't allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Be shure you use PHP 7.1 or higher

**FROM 7.1.0**
getenv() no longer requires its parameter. If the parameter is omitted, then the current environment variables will be returned as an associative array.

Comment: My php is on "PHP Version 7.3.9". And getenv() without parameter works, but only partially. As I said it does return an array of size 23, but my variable is not there.